# Python: communication between an app and terminal which is asking for Admins password

Tags: python, pexpect

I’m trying to accomplish the following but no luck, any suggestions?
⇒ My app will run a command that requires admin’s password, if you run the command in Terminal, the command will stop asking for the password, however, if you run it within Python, it will just skip that and will end with error (as Admin's password weren't entered. I have used **elevate** module to launch the app as root, however, the command im using doesn't allow to run as a root :

> Do not run this script with root privileges. Do not use 'sudo'

Any suggestions how to communicate between cli and python when cli is waiting for the admins password instead of just skipping it?
Thank you all

My  code:

```
Import os

os.system('killall Box')
os.system('/Library/Application\ Support/Box/uninstall_box_drive')
```

Result:

```
    /usr/local/bin/python3.10 /Users/user/PycharmProjects/pythonProjectBoxUnsaved/venv/test.py
No matching processes belonging to you were found
Unload failed: 5: Input/output error
Try running `launchctl bootout` as root for richer errors.
0
/usr/bin/fileproviderctl
File provider com.box.desktop.boxfileprovider/Box not found. Available providers:
 - iCloud Drive (hidden)
    com.apple.CloudDocs.MobileDocumentsFileProvider
    ~/L{5}y/M{14}s
fileproviderctl: can't find domain for com.box.desktop.boxfileprovider/Box: (null)
No matching processes belonging to you were found
sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper
sudo: a password is required

* * * * * *

Process finished with exit code 0
```

[Error when trying to run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZWXG.png)

[Error when using 'elevate' module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGlRI.png)

I have also tried pexpect, will not work, code below:

```
import os
import pexpect

os.system('killall Box')
child = pexpect.spawn('/Library/Application\ Support/Box/uninstall_box_drive')
print(child.after)
child.expect_exact('Password:')
print(child.after)
child.sendline('my_password')
print(child.after)
```

result below:

None

b'Password:'

b'Password:'

Comment: The `pty` and `expect` modules run pseudo-terminals and may be able to handle the password. Does the app have an alternate method for handing in the password when not running in a terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Had to include Bash path in the spawn arguments:

```
cmd = "/Library/Application\ Support/Box/uninstall_box_drive"
child = pexpect.spawn("/bin/bash", ["-c", cmd])
```